# PHP get first row from SQL database

Tags: php, sql

In a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtFXY.png) I am developing, you can see that there is a person with the best known time. I would like to show it in my page, and so I used this code:

```
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");

  if( $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT playername FROM 1_toad_circuit /*name of the table*/ LIMIT 0 , 30") ) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result2);
      printf ("%s \n", $row[0]);
    }
```

As output I am not getting Itoi6 (person with the best time), but I have Catfish (the first in alphabetical order). I have 3 columns as you can see on the picture ([link](http://prntscr.com/2gluuy)).

I say that I am pretty new with SQL and I would like to know what do I have to fix.

Comment: What columns are in the table? (update you question with this)

Comment: I'm curious why you are not limiting the SQL query to 1 result since you are retrieving only one in PHP..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your statement and then order by whichever field you are storing the times in.

For example, if you had a "time" field:

```
SELECT playername, time FROM 1_toad_circuit 
ORDER BY `time` ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Maybe `LIMIT 1` instead since he is only wanting one record? (I know he put 0,30 - but it doesn't seem it is what he ultimately needs.

Comment: +1 it works. I just wanted to know: If I want to add the time on my page, the code should become like `SELECT playername,time FROM 1_toad_circuit ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 0, 30`? And then I'll type a printf ("%s %s \n", $row[0],$row[1]);

Comment: @AlbertoRossi - Yes, adding that would work. It seems unnecessary to return up to 30 records when you only need 1, though.

Comment: @AlbertoRossi You should mark dethtron5000's response as the answer since it helped you.

Comment: Yes but I have to wait 4 minutes before accepting it ;) The site shows me this hint

Comment: @AlbertoRossi I'll update the answer to include the limit and other fields.